# Apache POI upgrade from 3.9 to 5.0

Tags: excel, maven, apache-poi

I am using apache POI 3.9 right now to generate excel sheets. Can I directly upgrade to version 5.0?
What kind of issue I may face?

Comment: [Apache POI 3.9 was released in 2012 and there have been a lot of changes in the last 9 years!](http://poi.apache.org/devel/history/changes-3x.html#3.9). You will find quite a few of the int-based method signatures have moved to enums

Comment: If you upgrade and haven't used a dependency manager like maven or gradle, please also get used to using one. there are already too many "I've upgraded to POI X.Y and I get a ClassCast or ClassNotFound exception" questions here